# Post stats missing from 'Review | Reopen Votes'

Tags: bug, review

When using the 'review' tool on the top menu, there is typically some stats to the right of the page, including a link to the original post.

[image]

When you flip to the 'Revision' tab of the 'review | Reopen Votes' page, that right-bar information is missing.

[image]

Having those stats (and particularly the link to the original post) is useful.

Can that be added back in?